# React Native putting different User Inputs in one Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-input

I am trying to put together a simple Question Answer Quiz with React Native. That said I want to store both the question and the answer in one object.

Currently I am running into trouble with the following codepieces:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Button,
    View,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity
  } from 'react-native'
```

```
const Test = () => {
const[card, setValues] = useState({
    title: '',
    question: '',
    answer: ''
})
const updateField = e => {
    setValues({
      ...card,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
};
        <TextInput
            placeholder='Kartentitel eingeben..'
            name = "title"
            value={card.title}
            onChangeText={updateField}>
        </TextInput>
        <TextInput
            placeholder='Fragestellung eingeben..'
            name = "question"
            value={card.question}
            onChangeText={updateField}>
        </TextInput>
        <TextInput
            placeholder='Antwortmöglichkeit eingeben..'
            name = "answer"
            value={card.answer}
            onChangeText={updateField}>
        </TextInput>
}
export default Test;
```

However I get the following Error
ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.target.value')
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SAgM.png)

I've got the idea behind this from react(not react native) posts and tutorials.
Basically what this is trying to do is to get each corresponding UserInput value and put it into the object target(this is what the updateField function should do)

Any help would really appreciated

Richard

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because e is not an HTMLInputChange event, I think that the onChangeText functions expects a functions with just a string argument.

You could wrapp the updateField function with another function that expects a name something like this:

```
const updateField = (name) => (value) =>{
   setValues({
      ...card,
      [name]: value
    });
}
```

And use it like this

```
 <TextInput ... onChangeText={updateField("title")} />
```

This should work, although I recommend using something like Formik to make form validations and handle the value changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked just the way I wanted to

Answer (score 0):

Difference between `onChangeText` and `onChange` is that the argument on `onChangeText` is the actual value only whereas the argument on `onChange` is the event itself. So try replacing `onChangeText` with `onChange`.

```
<TextInput
  placeholder='Antwortmöglichkeit eingeben..'
  name = "answer"
  value={card.answer}
  onChange={updateField}>
</TextInput>
```